# Using underscorejs inside an express application?

Tags: javascript, express, underscore.js-templating

I don't like jade I spent time figuring out how to use HTML instead this is what I came up with.

Installed ejs first, then implemented the code below for HTML.

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile); 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render(__dirname + '/views/page.html', {
    string: 'random_value',
    other: 'value'
  });
});
```

All is well until I need to pull a collection from the server and render some underscore syntax on my page.html

something like

```
<script type="text/template" id="messages">
    <%= message %>
</script>
```

I came across a stackoverflow post mentioning something was needed in addition to use a template engine, but I didn't pay much attention to it and cant find that piece of info.

**Edit:** I changed some code, it still is not working. `name is not defined at eval` "name" is the attribute I am trying to get from my model.

In my backbone.js code I have code like this.

```
window.App.Views.Message = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#messages').html()),
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Then inside my server code I have this.

```
var engines = require('consolidate');

app.engine('html', engines.underscore);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render(__dirname + '/views/page.html', {
    string: 'random_value',
    other: 'value'
  });
});
```

Inside page.html I have

```
<script type="text/template" id="messages">
    <% name %>
</script>
```

Running the node server I get `name is not defined at eval`

**Edit:** Trying to use mustache.js now, let's see how this goes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it to work with underscore.js here is what I did.

In my backbone.js code, I modified how I got the underscore template instead of

`template: _.template($('#messages').html()),`

I used it as a variable

`var tpl = _.template($('#messages').html(), {data: data});`

and of course passed my data into it `var data = this.model.toJSON();`

```
window.App.Views.Message = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        var data = this.model.toJSON();
        var tpl = _.template($('#messages').html(), {data: data});       
        this.$el.append(tpl);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Then in my html

```
<script type="text/template" id="messages">
    <%= data.name %>
</script>
```